# No Native Splash screen registered for given view controller. Call "splashscreen.show" for given view controller first

Tags: ios, react-native

I have tried using `react-native-splash-screen`, I have tried renaming LaunchScreen.storyboard, I have tried adding a new one to my images.xcassets folder. I am not sure what else I can try to avoid this warning. One thing I am a bit uncertain of which could be a contributing cause is how I am calling `react-native-splash-screen`, in my AppDegelate.m file, I have the following:

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"appName"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  [AppCenterReactNative register];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [RNSplashScreen show]; // here
  return YES;
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated :)

[image]